# multiple file validation inside a loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I use Laravel file validation to a multiple file inside a loop?

Usually in a single file validation, I can just do like

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'image' => 'image|max_width:1000|max_height:1000'
]);
if($validator->fails()){
    //validation fails
}
```

but now I want to validate multiple files in a single process, like

```
//store to a variable
$file = $request->file('image');
if($file){ //if request file image exist
    foreach($request->file('image') as $i){
    //here, validate each file image, but it just I don't know how
    }
}
```

Now for the front end side, to elaborate about the process of sending multiple files in one post.

```
$(document).on("change",'input[type="file"]',function(){
    if($(this).val()!==""){
        var files = this.files;
        handleFileUpload(files);
        $(this).val("");
    }
});

function handleFileUpload(files)
{
    //create a formData
    var fd = new FormData();
    //loop through e
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
    {
        //append each file object to the formData
        fd.append('image[]', files[i]);
    }
    //this function is where ajax request will be process
    sendFileToServer(fd); 
}
```

and so in the back end if I dump the request, I get these

> array(2) { [0]=> object(Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)#214 (7) {
>   ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   bool(false)
>   ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   string(50) "12400457_643171672489204_2452820305362127031_n.jpg"
>   ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   string(10) "image/jpeg"
>   ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   int(18413)
>   ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   int(0) ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(25)
>   "C:\wamp64\tmp\phpBAE4.tmp" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
>   string(11) "phpBAE4.tmp" } [1]=>
>   object(Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)#217 (7) {
>   ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   bool(false)
>   ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   string(39) "13296200_702501119889592_55691535_n.jpg"
>   ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   string(10) "image/jpeg"
>   ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   int(95383)
>   ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   int(0) ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(25)
>   "C:\wamp64\tmp\phpBAE5.tmp" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
>   string(11) "phpBAE5.tmp" } }

any ideas, clues, help please on how to use Laravel file validation on a multiple files inside a loop?

PS: I'm running on Laravel 5.2

Comment: checked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079240/validating-multiple-file-uploads-with-laravel-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending the `image` file input field as an array and then using array validation. If you're using Laravel 5.2 you can use **Array Validation** and ditch the foreach loop for building the rules.

Firstly, you would need to set up your file input as an array...

If you're using one input field:

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" multiple>
```

Your request would then come through looking something like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "oX3sTXPDnNiVj9mX20VOHe2xo1Ahx6sWzU4VHZxh"
  "image" => array:2 [▼
    0 => UploadedFile {#147 ▶}
    1 => UploadedFile {#146 ▶}
  ]
]
```

Then using array validation your rules would be declared in the validator by utilising the asterix symbol to indicate an array field:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'image.*' => 'image|max_width:1000|max_height:1000'
]);
```

Check the docs here for more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: Same here, same idea, I already applied it, thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
    foreach($this->input('image') as $key => $value){
        $rules['image.'.$key] = 'image|max_width:1000|max_height:1000';
    }
```